# insert array on stdClass on PHP

Tags: php

i have an array like this on php

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 10
            [b] => 8
            [c] => 4
        )
)
Array
(
     [z] => stdClass Object
         (
             [d] => 99461
             [e] => asldfjs
         )
)
```

how to push a second array to become like this or kind like this??

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 10
            [b] => 8
            [c] => 4
            [other_array]  => array (
                [d] => 99461
                [e] => asldfjs    
            )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that a `stdClass Object` is *not* an array...

However if you *really* want to set a property `other_array` inside that object, then just do it:

```
$myArray[0]->other_array = $otherArray;
```

Explanation: `$myArray[0]` is an *object*, according to your own statement. You can set any property in an object in php, but you have to use the object property notation (`->`), not an array notation. Simply because an object is *not* an array...

Comment: my godness you'r right, i has ben try using array_push  and always fail. thanks @arkascha

Comment: @sidzaky You should actually have gotten a warning when trying to feed an object as argument into `array_push()`... Enabling some form of error logging _and looking into the logfile_ usually saves a lot of time and frustration... :-)

Comment: actually i never got any warning and its soo waste much time, i has try this for 3 hour to push that array to another array haha. you got my thanks @arkascha

Comment: You should certainly find out _why_ you did not get any warning / error. Most likely you did not look where you should have? One should _always_ monitor the error log file in case of strange things going on. That should be part of the normal things you do in that case. If there _really_ is no entry in there (which I doubt...), then take a look at your php configuration and make sure you did not disable notices and warnings getting logged for convenience. Though that sounds like a nice thing one should _never_ do that. Such output is very valuable for a developer, one should never ignore it.